# Where does the cofactor expression in the expansion of minors formula come from?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So I know that the formula for the determinant of a matrix by expansion of minors is: 
$$\sum_{c=1}^n a_{rc}a'_{rc}$$ is the expansion of minors by a row
and 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n a_{rc}a'_{rc}$$ is the expansion of minors by a column.

In both expressions $a'_{rc} = (-1)^{r+c}\det(A)$ where r,c and A are respectively the row, column, and matrix $A$. I'm not sure how this expression for the cofactor is derived? Where does it come from? Is there a way to intuitively understand where it comes from?

Comment: You mean the determinant of the matrix with row $r$ and column $c$ removed, not the original matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you consider to be the primary definition of determinant. If you define it with the Leibniz formula
$$ \det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)}$$
where the sum is over all permutations of $[1,\ldots,n]$, then the minor
expansion over row $i$ is just picking out, for each element $a_{ij}$ in that row, the terms involving that element.